# Connect audio device with bluetooth dongle

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, bluetooth, dongle, wireless-headset

a couple months ago i bought a Bluetooth 3.0+EDR headset (Philips SHB7000).
Now i can connect with my phone without problems. But my laptop hasn't Bluetooth build-in, so i bought a   Bluetooth 4.0 dongle.

I've installed the drivers, and it can perfectly find and connect with any other device, but not with my headset.

The laptop is running Windows 8.1, and multiboot Windows 10 preview. They both don't work.

In the driver software i can see a list of services that are compatible with the dongle, such as:

- Handsfree
- Stereo
- Headset

  I turn on the headset (blue led flickering), than search for devices, but it won't find anything, but other devices.

Does somebody got an idea what the problem can be?

Comment: It's important to know what OS are you running on your laptop, because there appear to be issue with some Windows 7 connections.

Comment: @CharlieRB Updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself have a SHB7000 too.
You say that you have blue lights blinking.
These lights should be alternating between blue and white instead.
Hold the poweron button longer to make the device visible. ;)

Comment: Whoow thanks! Forgot to hold it longer if you want to connect for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are having compatibility issues between the three devices; computer, dongle and headset. Here is what the user manual states about compatibility.

> Your headset is compatible with Bluetooth enabled mobile phones. It
>   features Bluetooth version 3.0. It also works with devices featuring
>   other Bluetooth versions that support the Headset profile (HSP),
>   Hands-Free profile (HFP), Advanced Audio Distribution profile (A2DP)
>   and Audio/Video Remote Control profile (AVRCP).

I might note the manual focuses on **mobile phones**. There is a lot of discussion about this issue on Philips' forum; [SHB7000 Windows 7 Bluetooth Driver Problem](http://www.supportforum.philips.com/en/showthread.php?14340-SHB7000-Windows-7-Bluetooth-Driver-Problem) & [SHB7000 not working on windows 7](http://www.supportforum.philips.com/en/showthread.php?13791-SHB7000-not-working-on-windows-7).

Comment: I'm running Windows 8, so i think this is not relevant. In the questions is told that the headphones work on Windows 8. Also, my laptop doesn't even detect the headphones.

Comment: Your question is *"Does somebody got an idea what the problem can be?"* So that is what I answered. It is likely that if your computer were Bluetooth capable, without the dongle, the headphones might work. Keep in mind, just because you plug a dongle into the computer doesn't make it HSP, HFP, A2DP and AVRCP compatible.